# Trying to prove that for a curve $C$, that is parameterized by $\gamma (s)$, is spherical, i.e. every point of $C$ lies on a sphere.

Tags: differential-geometry, parametric

I have been presented with the problem where I have to prove that for a curve $C$ that is parameterized by $\gamma (s)$, where are $\gamma (s)$ has unit-speed, is spherical, i.e. every point of $C$ lies on the sphere $\mathbb{R}^3$. We also suppose that $\gamma (s)$ is spanned by a normal vector $n(s)$ and the binormal vector $b(s)$ for every $s$ that passes through a given fixed point $x_0$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I have only begun my study of differential geometry so I am quite stuck as to where to start the proof. But, I do know that for $\gamma (s)$ to be unit-speed: $|| \dot \gamma(s) || = 1$. Also, that $n(s) = \frac{\ddot \gamma (s)}{\kappa (s)}$ and $b(s) = t(s) \times n(s)$, where $t(s) = \dot \gamma (s)$.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The condition $\gamma$ is spanned by $n$ and $b$ means that

$$t(s)\cdot\gamma(s) = 0$$

for all $s$.

Comment: So that would imply that the parameterization is perpendicular to its derivative.

Comment: @Noel yes that's correct